# How can I get the length of a property in a jsonb in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, string-length

```
product
---------------------------
{"id":1, "code": "1231313"}
```

this is the query i made, but it doesn't work

`SELECT * FROM public.order WHERE "product" ->> LENGTH('code') = '7';`

I would like to know how I can get the length of the value of this property from a jsonb, please help me, thanks.

Comment: Select * From public.order WHERE length (product->>'code')=7;. Did you try this?

Comment: I just tried it, thanks it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the way to use the ->> operator to extract field from a column of type JSON(B) and then apply length() to get the text length.

```
select * from public.order where length(product->>'code') >= 7
```

See the various operators/functions to get data from JSON(B) column type, Postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html)